# Custom iOS (staging) configuration for React Native App

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, environment-variables, development-environment

I have created a Staging Configuration for my React Native application as a clone of my Release build. However, when I run `react-native run-ios --configuration Staging`, my build fails with:

```
Installing build/Build/Products/Staging-iphonesimulator/flockCover.app
An error was encountered processing the command (domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain, code=2):
Failed to install the requested application
An application bundle was not found at the provided path.
Provide a valid path to the desired application bundle.
Print: Entry, ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist

Command failed: /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c Print:CFBundleIdentifier build/Build/Products/Staging-iphonesimulator/myApp.app/Info.plist
Print: Entry, ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist
```

After inspection of the build, it appears that a few things are going wrong:
1) CodeSign is running on the Release build like so:

`CodeSign build/Build/Products/Release-iphonesimulator`

2) Symbols are being generated from the Release build:

`GenerateDSYMFile build/Build/Products/Release-iphonesimulator/flockCover.app/PlugIns/flockCoverTests.xctest.dSYM build/Build/Products/Release-iphonesimulator`

Various other things are pointing at Release.

Further inspection suggest this is because my (build) environment variables are being set incorrectly, eg:

```
export BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR=/Users/name/github/company/app/ios/build/Build/Products/Release-iphonesimulator
export CODESIGNING_FOLDER_PATH=//Users/name/github/company/app/ios/build/Build/Products/Release-iphonesimulator/flockCover.app
export CONFIGURATION=Staging
export CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=/Users/name/github/company/app/ios/build/Build/Products/Release-iphonesimulator
export CONFIGURATION_TEMP_DIR=/Users/name/github/company/app/ios/build/Build/Intermediates/ReactNativeConfig.build/Staging-iphonesimulator
```

Additionally, all of the third party libraries (E.g. React-Native, Yoga) Are running in Release mode resulting in things like:

```
export CLASS_FILE_DIR==/Users/name/github/company/app/ios/build/Build/Intermediates/ReactNativeConfig.build/Release-iphonesimulator/ReactNativeConfig.build/JavaClasses
```

An interesting note, not all things point at Release, besides the final error message, there is also things like:

`=== BUILD TARGET myApp OF PROJECT myProject WITH CONFIGURATION Staging ===`

`Ld build/Build/Intermediates/flockCover.build/Staging-iphonesimulator` (not to mention the `CONFIGURATION` environment variable above.

So my question is as follows:
1) How do I correctly set these environment variables(specifically `CODESIGNING_FOLDER_PATH`, `CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR`, etc.
2) How can I have a build in a dependent library that does not have the same configuration as my app (e.g. React). Do I need to create a Configuration there too?
3) Is this even what is causing my problem in the first place?

Comment: any luck with that? I am facing the same problem